# Google API key security for iOS apps

Tags: api, security, google-api, api-key, google-directions-api

**TLDR:**

Does Google check the validity of an iOS app's bundle identifier when restricting the API key to a specific iOS app?

Or is it possible for anyone to mimic the bundle ID in order to launch an attack?

If the latter is false, why not include the API key in the iOS app?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I'm guessing Google doesn't check for Team ID?

[Apple Glossary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Glossary/Glossary.html)

> App ID  A string that identifies one or more apps from a single team. An App ID consists of a bundle ID search string preceded by the Team ID, a 10-character string generated by Apple to uniquely identify a team.

---

I need some directions... (pun intended)

Say I'm building an iOS app that needs to consume the Google Directions API.

Google suggests to "proxy the web service via your server when you're using the API in a mobile app, to protect your API key".

In my project settings in Google Console (API Manager -> Credentials etc) I can restrict the API key to only iOS apps with my bundle identifier (com.example.MyApp).

Since I don't need a server, what's the worse that can happen if I include the key in the app?

The only thing I can think of right now is someone steals the API key and builds an app faking my bundle ID (or even fake the iOS host itself) and fires "unlimited requests" to bring down my service/make me pay a lot of money.

Is this possible?

And if it is, couldn't he do the same even if I hid the API key in the server? Just call my server instead of the API directly.

So what's the gain of having a server in that case?

And would the only solution to prevent this abuse be to require authentication and rate limit each user?

But couldn't then someone create "unlimited" random accounts?!

Do I use captcha?

By then the UX has become pretty awful, especially since authorisation is not even required for my app...

Is there a solution to this, or do I just choose the simplest solution (include the key in the app) and hope for the best?